# What is a recommended schema / database design to store custom report settings in my sql database?

Tags: sql-server, json, database-design, report

I am building a tool to allow people to create customized reports.  My question resolves around getting the right database schema and design to support some custom report settings.

In terms of design, I have various **Slides** and each **Slide** has a bunch of settings (like date range, etc).  A **Report** would basically be an ordered list of slides

The requirements are:

1. A user can create a report by putting together a list of "Slides" in any order they wish
2. A user can include the same slide twice in a report with different settings

So I was thinking of having the following tables:

**Report Table:**  Id, Name, Description
**Slide Table:**, Id, Description
**ReportSlide Table:**  ReportId, SlideId, Order, SlideSettings

my 2 main questions are:

1. **Order**: Is this the best way to manage the fact that a user can order their slides on any given report
2. **SlideSettings:** since every slides has a different set of settings (inputs), i was thinking of storing this as just a json blob and then parsing it out on the front end.  Does anything one think this is the wrong design?  Is there a better way to store this information (again, each slide has different inputs and you could have the same slide listed twice in a report each with different settings

Comment: I think the downvote may be because Stack Overflow considers "the best way" questions as subjective and open to diverse opinion.

Comment: How will the report be generated? Do you query the slides for the report in something like `PHP` and then parse the data, to make new queries based on a single slide and then retrieve the information? Or will al your slides be parsed into one big query that returns the report data?

Comment: If you're using sql server, you could store the blob as XML instead to take advantage of SQL Server's native XML querying capabilities.

Comment: @Mansfield -  i don't see myself needing to query any of these properties

Comment: @leora Even from a parsing perspective, if you use xml you can let the engine parse it out rather than having to do it in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Order: Is this the best way to manage

It is the correct way.

> SlideSettings: ... storing this as just a json blob

If you never intend to query these values, then that's fine.

You may want to rename `ReportSlide` to `SlideInReport`. A relationship should not just list the referenced tables, but the nature of the relationship.

Some (me) prefer to give PK-columns and FK-columns the same name. Then you cannot get away with just `Id`, but you need to call them `sld_id, rep_id`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should have a Settings table. You may also need a ValueTypes table to define which setting can take what kind of values. (such as Date Range). And then let the list of setting IDs be stored against a slide.

Needless to say, these "best way"s will depend on type and amount of data being stored etc. Am a novice in JSON etc, but as far as I read, it's not a good idea to keep JSON strings as database fields, but not a rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think, from a high level view, your schema will work. However, you might consider revising some of the table structure. For example:

**Settings**

Rather than a JSON blob, it may be best to add columns for each setting the ReportSlide table. Depending on what inputs you allow, give a column for each. For example, your date range will need to have StartDate/EndDate, Integers, Text fields, etc.

What purpose does the Slide Table serve? If your database allows a many-to-many relationship between Slides and Reports, then the ReportSlide table will hold all your settings. Will your Slide Table have attributes? If not, then perhaps Report Slides are all you need. For example:

```
Report Table: ReportID | DateCreated | UserID | Description
ReportSlides Table: ReportSlideID | ReportID | SlideOrder | StartDate | EndDate | Description...
```

Unless your Slide table is going to hold specific attributes that will be common across every report, you don't need the extra joins or space.

Depending on the tool, you may also want to have a `DateCreated`, `UserID`, `FolderID`, etc. Attributes that allow people to organize their reports.

If the Slides are dependent on each other, you will want to add constraints so Slide 2 cannot be deleted if Slide 3 depends on it.

**Order**

Regarding order, having a `SlideOrder` column will work. Because each `ReportSlideID` will have a corresponding Report, the `SlideOrder` can still be changed. That way, if `ReportSlideID = 1` belongs to `ReportID = 1` and has specific settings, it can be ordered 7th or 3rd and still work.

Be aware of your naming convention. If the Order column is directly referencing Slide Order, then go ahead and name it SlideOrder.

I'm sure there are a million other ways to make it efficient. That's my initial idea based on what you've provided.

Comment: The issue is that each "slide type" has different settings so this table would wind up having 100+ columns but only certain cols would be meaningful to certain types and i don't need to ever queries these fields

Comment: How many Slide Types are there? The issue is that if you want Slide Types to be used, with different configurations, across multiple reports, then you'll have to put those settings somewhere accessible. If certain columns are only meaningful to certain types, then perhaps widen your table structure. Include a SlideType table which would correlate SlideTypes with ReportSlides (in ReportID 1, which SlideTypes are used.)

Comment: In the SlideType table you could have one column per data type allowed (two dates for start/end date, text fields for description, etc.) Then when you pull that data back into your tool and label it according to SlideType/ReportID. The ReportSlide table would then just tell you which Report it belongs to, Which SlideTypes it's using, and in what order those SlideTypes should appear. That way there not all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

**Report Table**: ID (Primary Key), Name, Description,....

**Slide Table**: ID (PK), Name, Description,...

**Slide_x_report Table**: ID(PK), ReportID (FK), SlideID (FK), order

**Slide_settings Table**: ID(PK), NameSetting, DescriptionSettings, SlideXReportID (FK),...

I think that you shoud have a structure like this, and in the Slide_settings table you will have the setting of the differents slides by reports.

Imagine that the slide_settings table may contain dynamic forms and these should relate to a specific slide of a report, in this way you can have it all properly stored and the slide_settings table, you would have only columns that are needed to define an element of slide.

Comment: Why separate slide settings and slide x report in separate tables ?

Comment: Beacause for each Slide-Report you can have many elements to setting. if you had this in the same table, there would be redundant information in reportid and slideId columns, and also you could not have a primary key and simple, if you should have a primary key composed using report, slide and more elements configuration